# Pyinstaller only the .exe and nothing else

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Is there any way to run pyinstaller and not generating the pycache, build and .spec files?
And put the .exe in a specific path?

Comment: I found the list of options for pyinstaller here: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html

Try the --onefile flag and --clean

Comment: Well, I knew for the --onefile and the clean. The problem is that its still generating the other files... I would like to make a exe file that can create exe files. There as to be a solution, but I can't find it.

Comment: So. I found out that I can use the flag py distpath and workpath. Only issue is : how to give the null value ?

pyinstaller --onefile --clean --distpath . --workpath NULL test.py